# Circular reference causing stack overflow with Mapster

Tags: c#, mapster

Stack overflow exception with Mapster cause running process to terminate.

```
TSource.Adapt<TDestination>()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can find more about preventing circular reference from [doc](https://giters.com/dotnetchris/Mapster?amp=1#PreserveReference). Use following for preventing stack overflow error.

```
TypeAdapterConfig<TSource, TDestination>
    .NewConfig()
    .PreserveReference(true);
```